# ListBox Multi-Value String to Object

Tags: xpages

I have a ListBox where I need to restrict the number of options selected to two. I'm using 8.5.2 so cannot use the SSJS custom validator, but I can use a Java validator. The Java validator received the submittedValue as a comma-separated String.

The problem occurs if a value contains a comma. In that case, if I split the submittedValue String on commas, my code will think more options have been selected than actually have been.

When the value is written back into the underlying Notes Document, the conversion to getValue() has correctly mapped values. So if getSubmittedValue() was a single option from the ListBox that contained a comma, getValue() gives me a single element rather than two elements.

My query is how to reproduce the getSubmittedValue() to getValue() conversion, to correctly work out how many options have been selected.

Comment: Do not split by coma. If options are distinctive (no option can be found as a substring of another option), you can "cut them out" of submited value. First two win.

Comment: The problem is submittedValue separates them by commas and, as far as I can tell, there's no way to change that. I can't control whether the options contain commas, so selected options may include commas.

Comment: give some snippet and example options, please

Answer (score 0):

Paul, you actually can control the commas. The option has a display string and a value. You could substitute the comma for e.g. # and later before saving it back check if you have a # at the same position the display values have a , and save it then.

It's a lot more work - so not smart.

The other option: take the possible values out one by one:

- sort them by size, longest first (this way you avoid having a value that is contained in another value to screw up (e.g. "Red boat" vs "boat"
- take them out of the return string (if removal worked, then you have one, stop when you hit the 3rd)

.... but probably the easiest on is to do that in a little client side JavaScript counting the checked=checked values